# how come we are able to achieve Spring IOC without SpingIOC.jar

Tags: java, spring

Spring IOC is used to remove the tight coupling by avoiding object creation inside a class and instead doing it from bean.For this we would require Spring IOC Jar.

Now I have a doubt...

Suppose we dont use Spring IOC jar ..we use only Spring.jar and use ClassPathResource and XMLBeanFactory we are still accomplishment the same thing...

Now are we not accomplising the same thing as Spring IOC without using Spring IOC Jar...?

we are creating the objects not inside Class but using Bean.Is this not same we achieve in Spring IOC...?

If so then how are we able to achieve the same without using SpringIOC jar.?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of spring you are talking about. But the point is we can rename `SpringIOC.jar` to `Spring.jar` i.e. both can be the same. Or those might be with version difference(newer and older).

Answer (score 0):

Java classes are by-and-large oblivious to the name of the JAR file that contains them. (Not always, but mostly it's a bad idea to make them aware of such things as it just makes for headaches.)

Now, this means that Spring's implementation is largely agnostic to what JAR it is contained in, and in fact can be found distributed either as individual pieces (the Inversion-of-Control container is a foundational part) or as a combined build (often called `spring.jar`). Newer versions tend to only be available in split-down pieces, as it's a rare application that needs the whole of Spring 3 (it does a lot). I'm guessing that you are getting confused by this: the *same* classes can be present in *multiple* JAR files.

What a lot of people do is use a package management system (e.g., [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/index.html), though that's not the only one) to assemble the things that they depend on — together with their own code — into their application, when the exact list of what file they are in ceases to be very relevant any more. (Well, except for some types of management reporting, where every extra detail helps make the report look heavier…) To be fair, it is *not* easy to use such a system, but it is significantly simpler than trying to do the same job by hand and Spring is now sufficiently complicated to merit this approach.